# split xts object by index (date)

Tags: r, object, date, split, xts

I have an xts object that has intraday data:

```
head(stocks[,1])
                    SMH.close
2009-01-02 09:31:00     17.66
2009-01-02 09:32:00     17.66
2009-01-02 09:33:00     17.64
2009-01-02 09:34:00     17.60
2009-01-02 09:35:00     17.58
2009-01-02 09:36:00     17.63
```

I want to perform various analytics on intraday data but operations should not cross day boundaries. So what I want to do is split the data by date (ignoring the time). As such I extracted the index and saved unique date values by:

```
y <- index(stocks)
x <- strptime(y, format="%Y-%m-%d")
uniquedates <- unique(x)
```

Now I would like to do something similar to the example in ?split

```
> g <- airquality$Month
> l <- split(airquality, g)
```

Here the airquality data is split into a list object by the value of the Month column. I'm not sure how to do something similar as the date is the index in my case and not a data column. I tried but get an error.

```
> split(stocks, uniquedates)
Error in args[[i]] : subscript out of bounds
```

Perhaps there is a cleaner way of achieving what I want to do. I would greatly appreciate your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should skip the unique() step. Just use split.xts with an `f="days"` argument.

```
data(sample_matrix)
sample.xts <- as.xts(sample_matrix, descr='my new xts object')
split.xts(sample.xts, f="days")
[[1]]
               Open     High      Low    Close
2007-01-02 50.03978 50.11778 49.95041 50.11778

[[2]]
              Open     High     Low    Close
2007-01-03 50.2305 50.42188 50.2305 50.39767

[[3]]
               Open     High      Low    Close
2007-01-04 50.42096 50.42096 50.26414 50.33236

[[4]]
snipped
```

Comment: +1 but `split` is a generic, so you don't need to explicitly call `split.xts`.  `split(sample.xts, "days")` works.

Comment: Yes. I knew that but the arguments to split.xts are different than for split.default, so I decided to emphasize that difference.

Comment: Also, note that `split()` returns `zoo` objects, while `split.xts` returns `xts`/`zoo` objects.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you're looking for `apply.daily` (or `period.apply` in general)?

Comment: The period.apply functions will definitely come in use but I also want to compute various statistics - some rolling and others probability based - at every time increment X intraday. For example I want to know how many stocks are up / down at time = X * n (where n is an integer). As a result I think I need to split the data by day but perhaps there is a cleaner way preparing the data.

Comment: We could suggest the best alternatives if you gave a more complete example of what you're trying to do.